# Why is my SVR fitting taking forever to finish?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, stock

Hello everyone and hello world. This is my first StackOverflow question and any help would be great!

I am trying to create a simple Support Vector Regression (SVR) model for stock prediction using local stocks and using `sklearn.svm`'s `SVR`.

`train` is my training dataframe while
the dataframe only has date and closing price as its columns

`GSCV()` is a function which returns the optimal `C` and `gamma` derived from using `GridSearchCV`

```
        train["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(train["Date"])
        dates = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(train["Date"]).reshape(-1,1)
        closing_prices = (pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(train[' Close'])).reshape(-1,1)

        c,g = GSCV('rbf',dates, closing_prices)
        svr_rbf = SVR('rbf', C=c, gamma = g, cache_size=20000)

        c,g = GSCV('linear',dates, closing_prices)
        svr_lin = SVR(kernel= 'linear', C= c, gamma = g,cache_size=20000)

        c,g = GSCV('poly',dates, closing_prices)
        svr_poly = SVR(kernel= 'poly', C= c, degree= 2, gamma = g,cache_size=20000)

        svr_rbf.fit(dates, closing_prices)
        svr_lin.fit(dates, closing_prices)
        svr_poly.fit(dates, closing_prices)
```

I would like to mention that I have two types of datasets: low-variance stocks and high-variance stocks. When fed with the low-variance stocks, the models terminate immediately though with a constant prediction all throughout. On the other hand, the high-variance stocks are causing my non-termination issue.

My experiment needs to create models based on 2,4,6,8,10 years of data. At most, I have 2100+ datapoints, but even with only 400+ datapoints the code does not seem to terminate. Is this too many to begin with?

I have tried
    1. scaling the data using the `StandardScaler`
    2. setting the `cache=20000` in hopes of a speedup

Thanks for any and all input!

Answer (score 0):

As here is no infinity-loop or something, the code should terminate or give an error at some point in time, so first question: Did you run it to the end?

You could measure your RAM, to get an idea if it is running on high computational costs.

Otherwise here is a thread which could help: [How to speed up sklearn SVR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582669/how-to-speed-up-sklearn-svr?rq=1)